Continuity of sections of the structure sheaf of an affine variety
I am studying Gathmann's lecture notes (2002/03 version, available here). The author's definition of an affine variety (as a ringed space) is as follows:
Definition: An affine variety is a ringed space $ (X, O_X) $, where:

$X$ is an irreducible topological space,
$O_X$ is a sheaf of $k$-valued functions,
$X$ is isomorphic to an irreducible algebraic subset of some affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Question: Given an affine variety $ (X, O_X) $, are the sections of the structure sheaf $ O_X $ continuous functions when $ k $ (an algebraically closed field) is equipped with the Zariski topology?
Since the closed sets in $k$ are simply $\varnothing$, $k$, and finite sets, I think it would suffice to show that, if $\varphi \in O_X(U)$ for some open set $U$ and $\alpha \in k$, then $\varphi^{-1}(\alpha)$ is a finite set. In that case, if $Z(g) \neq \varnothing$ is a finite closed subset of $k$, then $\varphi^{-1}(Z(g))$ would also be finite, thus establishing continuity. However, I am not certain if this claim about $\varphi^{-1}(\alpha)$ is true.

Your argument doesn't work - try an example... Say $X=\mathbb A^2$ is the plane, and $\phi(x,y) = x$. Then $\phi^{-1} (0)$ is the $y$-axis.

You can refer to [Gathmann's lecture notes (Version of 2021/22), Lemma 3.4] for a proof.

However, certainly, in my example case of $X$ (the plane), any global section $\phi$ is a poly in two variables, so  if $\alpha\in k$, then $\phi^{-1}({\alpha}) "= {z\mid \phi(z)-\alpha =0} "$ is (by definition) a Zariski closed set.

A bit of nitpicking with your definition: When Gathmann says in Definition 2.3.15 that $X$ must be isomorphic to an affine variety in the sense of 1.3.1, then (from what I can tell) he means "isomorphic as ringed spaces" - i.e. not just as topological spaces. This implies that in particular, $\mathcal{O}_X$ is not just any sheaf of functions. Its sections are somehow naturally identified with polynomials.
